# Does Android Printer Framework Support Bluetooth Connection?

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, android-print-framework

I'm trying to print some pdf documents by using Android Printer Framework via Bluetooth Connection.

I could not print any document when I click **find all printers** it just holds and does not show any printer device.

Printer and Android tablet paired but there was no action.

How can I print documents using Android Printer Framework with Bluetooth Connection?

Comment: The printer manufacturer should have an app on the Play Store (and perhaps elsewhere) that serves as a "print driver", more or less. For example, [here is the one for HP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.printservice). Find and install that. If they do not seem to have such an app, contact the printer manufacturer's technical support for assistance.

Comment: @CommonsWare actually I'm trying for HP as well, I could not find any information about bluetooth, all the information was about wifi, internet connection. How can i print via Bluetooth any idea?

Comment: You will have to ask HP.

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin, Hi, I have same problem. Did you manage to print via Bluetooth or not yet?

Comment: @FARID I had to reverse engineer some Android app on Android Market, I could not find a proper way to print via Bluetooth that supports all printer models.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is YES. Android Print Framework support Bluetooth Connection. Check the document here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

> Android now includes a complete framework that allows users to print any document using a printer connected over Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, or other services. The system handles the transaction between an app that wants to print a document and the services that deliver print jobs to a printer. The android.print framework provides all the APIs necessary to specify a print document and deliver it to the system for printing. Which APIs you actually need for a given print job depends on your content.

But you need your printer's manufacturer to support Bluetooth too to print via Bluetooth. Ask the manufacturer about it. In the case of HP, it seems that it does not support Bluetooth at this time.

Answer (score 0):

StarPrint may do what you are looking for. It finds the connected printers, manages drivers, and so forth